# Mysql issue with retrieving information

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query, which is giving me some problems...

I am trying to export a query into a text file, and this function creates a data.txt file but it is returned empty.

The error message i get is:

> mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in .... on line 87

The code is:

```
$fh = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT $checked FROM hostess;");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $last = end($row);
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        fwrite($fh, $item);
        if ($item != $last)
            fwrite($fh, "\t");
    }
    fwrite($fh, "\n");
}
fclose($fh);
```

The line 87 is:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
```

What is wrong with this?

Thanks..

Comment: 1. What is contained in `$checked`? 2. What will be the final query, is it a valid MySQL query? 3. SQL Injection

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.. $checked is a variable i get from a checkbox.. and i have parsed it to this other file, i just need to put the $checked inside the query... and the result should be a text file downloaded with the information. I need to download a generated report..

Comment: Check the query. You may have an error there, get the text that is created and run it directly on mysql via phpmyadmin or console.

Comment: @GazetaAlmedicus Your code is very unsafe right now. If `$checked` comes from the outside, you should escape it before inserting into a query. If you are a beginner anyways, you should learn PDO prepared statements instead of the soon deprecated `mysql_` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use mysql_error() while using mysql methods to trace the errors..

Here even, you did not create the mysql connection. First add following lines in the starting of that code.

```
 $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
 if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 mysql_select_db('db');
```

Then run your code and don't forget to use add [mysql_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php). :):)

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT checked FROM hostess");
if ( !$result1 ) { 
    echo mysql_error();
}else{
     // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should listen for errors by `mysql_query()` to see what went wrong. In testing environments, this could look like the following:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT $checked FROM hostess");
if ( !$result1 ) { echo mysql_error(); }
// rest of the code
```

Comment: Hey.. it says no database selected :S

Comment: Also, you should remove the trailing `;` within the query, as in `$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT $checked FROM hostess");`

Comment: @GazetaAlmedicus So you should add the whole setting up a connection code ,-). Maybe should also check for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Hey thanks, i feel stupid, i hadn't selected a database... sorry, it is stupid to say of course! I should be more careful next time i ask :)